# adb cmd is not responding

Tags: android, adb

I'm using ADB on Windows10 for an Android Infotainment system product development. All the adb cmds are working OK on my Android phone. However, it just didn't work on the product I'm working on.
Couple issues:

1. The device constantly goes offline, I have to do kill-server and start-server frequently to make it online;
2. adb root, install, shell, etc. all cmds not responding. After input "adb install xxxx.apk" and ENTER, it just pending there without doing anything;
3. I set ADB_TRACE=1, and try again the above steps, it will return
   "**adb D 03-12 22:58:30 32144 40272 sysdeps_win32.cpp:151] _fh_from_int: invalid fd -2 passed to adb_close**"

Any help? Thank you very much!

Below is the cmd screen progress:

```
C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v>adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
S0J58X1ee07dc9  offline
    

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v>adb kill-server

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v>set ADB_TRACE=1

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v>adb start-server
adb D 03-12 22:58:28 32144 40272 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 22:58:28 32144 40272 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 22:58:28 32144 40272 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 22:58:28 32144 40272 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 22:58:28 32144 40272 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb D 03-12 22:58:28 32144 40272 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 32144 40272 sysdeps_win32.cpp:838] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot 
connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it. (10061)
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 32144 40272 sysdeps_win32.cpp:602] _socket_set_errno: mapping Windows error 
code 10061 to errno 22
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 55288 55284 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 55288 55284 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 55288 55284 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 55288 55284 adb_trace.cpp:187]
* daemon started successfully
adb D 03-12 22:58:30 32144 40272 sysdeps_win32.cpp:151] _fh_from_int: invalid fd -2 passed to 
adb_close

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v>cd Downloads

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb install "Pandora_2006.2_Patched.apk"
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:387] adb_query: host:features
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:features
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:features
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=17 
30303064686f73743a66656174757265 000dhost:feature [truncated]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303534 0054
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=84
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=84 got=84 
6162625f657865632c66697865645f70 abb_exec,fixed_p [truncated]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: abb_exec:settings
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: abb_exec:settings
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=18 
30303065686f73743a74706f72743a61 000ehost:tport:a [truncated]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:114] Switch transport in progress: host:tport:any
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=8
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=8 got=8 0200000000000000 
........
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:128] Switch transport success
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=64 
303033636162625f657865633a736574 003cabb_exec:set [truncated]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4641494c FAIL
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303036 0006
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=6
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=6 got=6 636c6f736564 closed
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:360] _adb_connect error: closed
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd -1
adb: failed to run abb_exec. Error: closed
adb: retrieving the default device installation mode failed: closedPerforming Streamed Install
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:402] adb_open: 'Pandora_2006.2_Patched.apk' => fd 
2048
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: abb_exec:package
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: abb_exec:package
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2049
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2049 len=18 
30303065686f73743a74706f72743a61 000ehost:tport:a [truncated]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:114] Switch transport in progress: host:tport:any
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2049 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2049 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2049 wanted=8
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2049 wanted=8 got=8 0200000000000000 
........
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:128] Switch transport success
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2049 len=40 
303032346162625f657865633a706163 0024abb_exec:pac [truncated]
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2049 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2049 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2049
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 2049
adb D 03-12 22:58:52 66736 66744 commandline.cpp:382] copy_to_file(2048 -> 2049)
^C
^C
C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb reboot
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: reboot:
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: reboot:
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=18 
30303065686f73743a74706f72743a61 000ehost:tport:a [truncated]
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:114] Switch transport in progress: host:tport:any
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=8
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=8 got=8 0200000000000000 
........
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:128] Switch transport success
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=11 303030377265626f6f743a 
0007reboot:
adb D 03-12 23:00:48 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4641494c FAIL
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303036 0006
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=6
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=6 got=6 636c6f736564 closed
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:360] _adb_connect error: closed
adb D 03-12 23:00:52 59856 70952 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd -1
error: closed

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb shell
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:387] adb_query: host:features
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:features
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:features
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=17 
30303064686f73743a66656174757265 000dhost:feature [truncated]
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4641494c FAIL
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303161 001a
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=26
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=26 got=26 
6e6f20646576696365732f656d756c61 no devices/emula [truncated]
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:360] _adb_connect error: no devices/emulators found
adb D 03-12 23:01:02 81708 81904 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd -1
adb.exe: no devices/emulators found

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:15 41520 41528 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:01:15 41520 41528 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:01:15 41520 41528 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:01:15 41520 41528 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:01:15 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
List of devices attached
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:387] adb_query: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a64657669636573 000chost:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303030 0000
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=0
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=0 got=0
adb D 03-12 23:01:16 41520 41528 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)


C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
List of devices attached
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:387] adb_query: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a64657669636573 000chost:devices
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303030 0000
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=0
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=0 got=0
adb D 03-12 23:01:19 68736 27936 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)


C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb devices
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
List of devices attached
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:387] adb_query: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:devices
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=16 
30303063686f73743a64657669636573 000chost:devices
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 30303137 0017
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=23
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=23 got=23 
53304a3538583165653037646339096f S0J58X1ee07dc9.o [truncated]
adb D 03-12 23:02:00 84396 84080 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)
S0J58X1ee07dc9  offline


C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb kill-server
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_client.cpp:194] adb_kill_server
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 sysdeps_win32.cpp:846] port 5037 type tcp => fd 2048
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=2048 len=13 30303039686f73743a6b696c6c 
0009host:kill
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=2048 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 sysdeps_win32.cpp:689] recv fd 2048 failed: An existing connection 
was forcibly closed by the remote host. (10054)
adb D 03-12 23:02:06 79208 87944 sysdeps_win32.cpp:537] adb_close: 2048(lo-client:5037)

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>set ADB_TRACE=1

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb start-server
adb D 03-12 23:02:25 70892 70888 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:02:25 70892 70888 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:02:25 70892 70888 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:02:25 70892 70888 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 03-12 23:02:25 70892 70888 adb_client.cpp:346] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb D 03-12 23:02:25 70892 70888 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 70892 70888 sysdeps_win32.cpp:838] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot 
connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
it. (10061)
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 70892 70888 sysdeps_win32.cpp:602] _socket_set_errno: mapping Windows error 
code 10061 to errno 22
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 86148 87728 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 86148 87728 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 31.0.0-7110759
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 86148 87728 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 86148 87728 adb_trace.cpp:187]
* daemon started successfully
adb D 03-12 23:02:27 70892 70888 sysdeps_win32.cpp:151] _fh_from_int: invalid fd -2 passed to 
adb_close

C:\Users\allen_1q47m7v\Downloads>adb install -r "Pandora_2006.2_Patched.apk"
```